# Is there any open databases where I can get how many decimal places are there for that currency?

Tags: decimal, currency

My app needs functionality where if User types Euro my app should be able to tell you how many decimal places are thereafter decimal point? for clarification like dollar has 100 cents so there are two decimal places after the decimal point, for example, 32.**56** $. My question is where can i get this type of data for most of the currencies in the world?

Comment: Most languages will have this functionality available in one or more packages/libraries for the language. E.g. in JavaScript, the [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) method can be told to format as currency and will do the right thing. Unfortunately, locating the specifics in your language a) would be an off-topic request here, b) not be possible since you've not told us your language and c) also depend on the *specifics* of your use case - formatting, parsing, etc?

Comment: I don't know of an open database, but the answer is here: https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-currency-besides-the-Chilean-peso-CLP-that-doesnt-use-cents ... of which only JPY is likely to matter to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is: the official list of currencies from ISO 4217, available as an [XML feed](https://www.six-group.com/dam/download/financial-information/data-center/iso-currrency/lists/list-one.xml).

It's not indexed by currency code but by country, so there is a bit of deduplication to be made. The field you're looking for is `CcyMnrUnts`:

```xml
<CcyNtry>
    <CtryNm>FRANCE</CtryNm>
    <CcyNm>Euro</CcyNm>
    <Ccy>EUR</Ccy>
    <CcyNbr>978</CcyNbr>
    <CcyMnrUnts>2</CcyMnrUnts>
</CcyNtry>
```

This is the list we use in the [brick/money](https://github.com/brick/money) library.

Comment: Outdated link. The current link is https://www.six-group.com/dam/download/financial-information/data-center/iso-currrency/lists/list-one.xml and can be found on this overview page: https://www.six-group.com/en/products-services/financial-information/data-standards.html#scrollTo=isin:~:text=Current%20Currency%20%26%20Funds